# SQL query is not producing expected results

Tags: sql, excel

I need to turn our data (first part of the picture) into a column wise version (second part of the picture).

My code so far is

```
StrQuery = "SELECT  CAST(readingDTTM AS DATETIME) DATETIME, rValue FROM
loggerData WHERE sName = 'Westoe' AND subName = 'Crown Shaft'" & _
"and Sensor = 'Depth' GROUP BY  CAST(readingDTTM AS DATETIME), rValue, Sensor"
```

but this only brings back the Depth. I need a further 2 columns for temperature and voltage.

[image: Images of Data]

Comment: Most people here want sample data and expected results as formatted text, not images.

Comment: Use `case` _expressions_ to do conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT  CAST(readingDTTM AS DATETIME) DATETIME,
case Sensor when 'Depth' then rValue end as Depth,
case Sensor when 'Temperature' then rValue end as Temperature
FROM loggerData 
WHERE sName = 'Westoe' AND subName = 'Crown Shaft'
and Sensor in ('Depth','Temperature') 
GROUP BY  CAST(readingDTTM AS DATETIME), rValue, Sensor`

or you could use pivot

Comment: ve added a new comment can you have a look please Waldermort? thanks for your help @Waldermort

Answer (score 0):

`select DATETIME,  max(Depth) Depth,  max(Temperature) Temperature from(
SELECT CAST(readingDTTM AS DATETIME) DATETIME, 
case Sensor when 'Depth' then rValue end as Depth, 
case Sensor when 'Temperature' then rValue end as Temperature 
FROM loggerData WHERE sName = 'Westoe' AND subName = 'Crown Shaft' 
and Sensor in ('Depth','Temperature') 
GROUP BY CAST(readingDTTM AS DATETIME), rValue, Sensor
    )
group by DATETIME`

--not pretty,  but it should work

Comment: its not liking the group by syntax ---- "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'group'." @waldermort  ... really appreciate this

Comment: please try again with last modification, maybe your database is case sensitive, otherwise I have no idea, why it should not work

Comment: it fails over on "Invalid object name 'loggerData'." now :( @waldermort

Comment: the semicolon at the end is causing problems

Comment: Morning... i cant see that updated query anymore the one that we got to work.. did you delete it? @waldermort

Comment: Hi @stephensmith, no, I did not. Last modification was removing the semicolon at the end in case you have copy pasted it with it in to the StrQuery  variable. You can see all versions here: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53498583/revisions